# Can't install ADT Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I followed the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing
but the installation froze, so I stopped it and tried to do it over again.

The package isn't installed (even after restarting eclipse) and when I try to do it again there is a duplicate location error ( when I try to Add Repository with "ADT Plugin" and "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/")

Where do I go to finish installing what I interrupted, or delete what I partially installed??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to available plugins, and remove the entry for ADT. Try adding it again and look at the error messages. You eclipse version might not have some dependencies that ADT has. If possible, get hold of the error messages and post them here.

Go to Install new plugins -> Available Software Sites.

[image]

Comment: ADT isn't listed anywhere, that is the problem. There is no evidence it has been installed and yet it prevents me from re-installing due to a duplicate location ...

Comment: Well, Look for the URL on the right pane. You should find something with "google" or "android" in it.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot.